# exe file creation

Tags: differential-equations

HOW CAN I MAKE IT exe FILE? PLEASE HELP...

```
a = Input["Enter the value of a="];
b = Input["Enter the value of b="];
d = Input["Enter the value of d="];
ans = DSolve[{a*x''[t] + b*x'[t] + d*
x[t] == Input["Enter the source term depending on time(funtion of time)"],
 x[Input["
    Enter initial time for displacement"]] == Input["enter 
            initial displacement"], 
          x'[Input["initial time for velocity"]] == Input["initail \
velocity"]}, x[t], t];
Print[ans];
Plot[x[t] /. ans, {t, Input["minimum value of t"], Input[
              "maximum value of t"]}];
If[(b^2 - 4*a*d)^(1/2) == 0, Print["CRITICALLY DAMPED MOTION
          "], If[(b^2 - 4*a*d)^(1/2) > 0, Print["OVER DAMPED MOTION"], \
Print["UNDER DAMPED MOTION"]]];
```

Comment: BTW, you're really creative